# Convert array of images to JSON file and decode it after C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I want to create an array that contains images and then exctract it as a JSON file. Then upload this file to a server. Then download this file to a project and after that I want to convert the JSON file back to the array of images that it was before so I can retrieve the images from inside of it. So how this encode-decode procedure can be achieved? Is that possible in C#? (I'm using Unity3D to be more exact)
Thanks

Comment: You can convert all of your images into base64 strings and create an array of these strings and convert it into JSON.  When you retrieve the JSON you can convert the base64 strings back to images.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use json for that? Did you look at asset bundles?

Answer (score 2):

In general storing binary data in a text based format is a bad idea ... it can be done but would require Base64 encoded strings ([`ToBase64String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string) and [`FromBase64String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string)) .. which requires way more memory than just the raw bytes themselves.

But yes you could probably use something like e.g.

```
// The root JSON object
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public List<ImageData> encodedImages = new List<ImageData>();

    // Empty constructor required by serializer
    public Root(){ }

    public Root(Texture2D[] textures)
    {
        foreach(var tex in textures)
        {
            encodedImages.Add(new ImageData(tex));
        }
    }
}

// Data for each encoded image/Texture2D
[Serializable]
public class ImageData
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int type;
    public string encodedData;

    // empty constructor required by serializer
    public ImageData() { }

    pubilc ImageData(Texture2D tex)
    {
        width = tex.width;
        height = tex.height;
        type = (int)tex.format;

        // Note that this is SLOW!
        var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();

        encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    public Texture2D GetTexture()
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);

        var tex = new Texture(width, height, (TextureFormat)type, false);
        tex.LoadRawTextureData(bytes);
        tex.Apply();

        return tex;
    }
}

public string Encode(Texture2D[] textures)
{
    var output = new Root(textures);

    return JsonUtility.ToJson(output);
}

public Texture2D[] Decode(string json)
{
    var root = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json);

    var count = root.encodedImages.Length;
    var output = new Texture2D[count];

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        output[i] = root.encodedImages[i].GetTexture();
    }

    return output.ToArray();
}
```

As said probably not very efficient though.

This would generate a JSON somewhat having a structure like e.g.

```json
{
    "encodedImages": 
    [
        {
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 1920,
            "type": 4,
            "encodedData": "U29tZSBCYXNlNjQgRW5jb2RlZCBJbWFnZSBEYXRhIEhlcmUh"
        },

        {
            "width": 800,
            "height": 600,
            "type": 4,
            "encodedData": "RXZlbiBtb3JlIEJhc2U2NCBlbmNvZGVkIGltYWdlIGRhdGEgaGVyZSE="
        },

        ....
    ]
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*